# best way to delete a record depending on what data permissions a user has MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

Take a record from the `customers` database as an example:

```
id, company, first_name, last_name, email, phone
'3', 'ABC Company', 'Kevins', 'kevinboy@gmail.com', 667-545-9502
```

And a sample record from the user permissions table:

```
user_id    table    column      add    delete    view
1       customers   company     1       1        1
1       customers   first_name  1       1        1
1       customers   last_name   1       1        1
1       customers   email       0       0        0
1       customers   phone       0       0        0
```

On our frontend, user 1 might be logged in, and the permissions table basically says that for any customer record, which fields do they have access to see. So from the customer record (id 3), on the front-end they would only see company, first and last name.

Normally, before permissions were implemented, on the frontend anyone could click a delete button, and a delete query was made `DELETE FROM customers WHERE id = 3`.

Now with permissions implemented, values for a record will only be returned where the user has view = 1 for a given table + column combo.

The question is, this works great for adding and editing a record. I was able to create logic on our API that checks specifically what the user is allowed to see. My challenge though is with DELETE. I have 2 ideas, and wanted to get some advice on the best approach, or if there is an easier way to achieve this directly in MySQL.

option 1) when a user sends a DELETE request to the API, I can take the customer id given and get the record from the db using a SELECT. Then, I can evaluate which fields have data, and which fields the user is permissioned to delete. Basically, if a record contains what they are permissioned to, then yes they can delete it, but if it contains values in other fields they are not permissioned to, then no they cant delete the record.
option 2) when the user sends a DELETE request to the API they can include the full record from the frontend. So I'd expect them to send all values for id 3 as shown above. In this case, i can also evaluate what they are sending me and what fields they have access to delete.

This query runs at the API level before ever adding, deleting a record.

```
SELECT column FROM permissions WHERE table = ? and delete = ? and user_id = ?
```

Comment: Maybe you can identify the permission using `CASE` expression in `SELECT` first. If the id met the criteria in the `CASE`, then only proceed with the delete query?

Comment: When user deletes a record he deletes all column values, hence he must have delete permissions on all table's columns. So you must check that `SUM(delete)` for this user and this table is equal to the amount of columns in the table (except `id` of course). For shown data the DELETE request must be ejected because sum is 3 whereas the table has 5 columns (user have no permissions to delete values from email and phone).

Comment: @akina interesting but what if the record contained null values for email and phone. Although he cant delete those fields, wouldnt it make sense that he could delete a record he has access to while the other fields are null or empty?

Comment: *but what if the record contained null values for email and phone.* NULL is a value. I do not see the reason to think that it is worse than any other value. This is the first. And the second - I think, main. Delete permissions on all columns does not mean delete permission on the row itself. For example, you have no permission on `id` - but this is a value too. So you must have additional permission type for this purpose. And respectively a permission on new row creation.